# What is profile 'app' in new android studio update?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just updated my android studio a couple of days ago and noticed that a new feature called `profile 'app'` added. Moreover, in the starting window of android studio there is a new option `Profile or debug app` also. What's the usage of this features and what are advantages of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio now allows you to `profile and debug any APK` without having to build it from an Android Studio project—as long as the APK is built to enable debugging and you have access to the debug symbols and source files.

Check `APK profiling and debugging` title in official information : https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html

**What is Profiling?**

> An app is considered to have poor performance if it responds slowly,
>   shows choppy animations, freezes, crashes, or consumes a lot of power.
>   To avoid these performance problems, use the profiling tools listed on
>   this page to identify where your app is making inefficient use of
>   resources, such as the CPU, memory, graphics, network, and device
>   battery.

This is the official information about how to use `Profile and Debug Pre-built APKs` feature : https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-debugger.html

Comment: Well elaborate.